# Condition not working in OR statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know this is common but I'm confused. Can someone explain what's the problem with my condition? The result below should reflect the else statement since the value of extension is 'Sr.'

```js
var extension = "Sr.";
if (extension != "Jr." || extension != "Sr." || extension != "I") {
  console.log("Should be false"); // the result goes here in if statement
} else {
  console.log("Should be True");
}
```

**The result of the code above is false it should be true**

Comment: Sr does not equal jr so it will be false. Today you learned the difference between AND and OR.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of [or logical operator not working javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61862469/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use "AND"(&&) statement to get your required output.
This will go into else block if the extension is any of (Jr, Sr, I).

```
var extension = "Sr.";
if (extension != "Jr." && extension != "Sr." && extension != "I") {
  console.log("Should be false"); 
} else {
  console.log("Should be True");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well you should read again about logic table

(extension !="Jr." || extension !="Sr." || extension !="I") <== **that mean if result one of these is true (match as result in above case it will return false if equal to extention value) than the else statement will be execute**

Change OR (||) to AND (&&) so all condition are meet with the case.

Comment: that's what I want but the result will goes to the if statement

Comment: value is Sr. and the logic result is there is one false

Comment: (true, false, true)

Comment: My suggention is change OR to AND so all condition are meet